# Android admob show banner ad over webview

Tags: android, admob

I want to show a banner ad over webview. But don't know how to do.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_ptv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techndroid.cricketlivestreaming.Ptv">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:id="@+id/webStream"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want ad to show top of the layout.

I think it goes behind the webview. I need to show over webview

Comment: for that you can use frame Layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show in RelativeLayout too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In java, just write:

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: If you show ad on your website or your own content, it will not ban. But if you show ad on Other's content like you have added facebook.com in your app and start showing ad, it will ban your account. For that Google may ban your dev account too! So careful :)

Comment: It shows 5 mins to wait. Please answer above question

Comment: Technically it works, but Simply don't do it! This is not allowed by google. 
You would, soon or later, receive a kind e-mail from google asking to fix it or get your ads disabled. I know by experience that google doesn't care whether the webview contains external websites or your own content.
You have to put the banner in a separate layout below or above the webview, although this ends up wasting more space from the display.

Comment: Thanks @P.Zaccaria Just edited the comment and fixed the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

For the solution you can use Frame Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_ptv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.techndroid.cricketlivestreaming.Ptv">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<WebView
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:id="@+id/webStream"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: give height to the add mob and then check and also it takes some time to load.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">




        <WebView

            android:id="@+id/webStream"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</FrameLayout>
```